# What can I use instead of tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTM in TensorFlow 2.x?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The `tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTM` is deprecated in TensorFlow 2.x. What is equivalent to this code or what can I use instead of it in TensorFlow 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tensorflow 2.x, you can use

```
tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell
```

For better performance, alternative is

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell
```